# Angular send an different type (enum) in the url when using routerLink

Tags: angular, enums, routerlink, angular-activatedroute

I have a button which has an routerlink.

On the "routedpage" there is an enum which decides what will be loaded on the page.

I like to send a param with the button so I can use it on the routed page.

```
<a routerLink="/all-countries">List of coutries</a>
```

I tried the activatedroute option but that needs a string in the url.

```
const name: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('somestring_but_need_an_enum');
```

is it not possible to send an @output when clicked on the button and use this on the routed page as an @Input.

If this is not the right method which method should I use.

Route module contains the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'detail/:name', component: CountryDetailComponent },
    { path: 'all-countries', component: AllCountriesComponent }
];
```

Comment: If I understand well your are trying to pass a parameter to the route from the template, correct? also, can you include the Route object?

Comment: what do you mean with the route object?

Comment: the routes of your app, or at least the one that you want to access, maybe the problem is there

Comment: your are missing the param declaration in your route "all-countries", if you add one you can use [routerLink]="['all-countries',param]"

Comment: thank you, but still I can't pass a enum value. the value must be a string

 <a [routerLink]="['/all-countries', someenum.somevalue]">List of all countries</a>

Comment: you can stringify the object